# SQL - Get the index of column that has maximum value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with sample data as below.

```
col1    col2    col3
4       6       9
7       1       5
```

I want to get the index of column that has value matches the maximum value on that row and If they are equal, just ignore the later.

For example, the result should be return

```
3 (because col3 has maximum value 9)
1 (because col1 has maximum value 7)
```

Please note that the number of columns is undefined, so I need a general solution.

Thank you

Comment: If they are equal what do you want?

Comment: If they are equal, just ignore the later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general solution (i.e. N columns) to this is to Unpivot the columns into rows, and then a windowing function can be applied to obtain the group wise maximum to each set of column 'rows'. You will however need some kind of key for each row, so that the maximum can be applied in row wise fashion (to allow reassembling the original rows). I've done this by adding a surrogate `Guid` via `newId()`. Note this returns the column NAME with the highest value in each row:

```
WITH MyTableWithRowId AS
(
    SELECT newId() AS Id, *
    FROM MyTable
),
Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT Ndx, Id, col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY col DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM 
    MyTableWithRowId tbl
    UNPIVOT
    (
      col for Ndx in(col1, col2, col3)
    ) p
)
SELECT Ndx
FROM Unpivoted
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32df1/5)

**Edit, re just '1, 2, 3' not the name of the column (col1, col2, col3)**

As per @Giorgi's comment, if you really want the (one based) ordinal position of the column in each row, you can join back into DMV's such as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to look up the ordinal, although this would be terribly fragile strategy IMO.

```
WITH MyTableWithRowId AS
(
    SELECT newId() AS Id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM MyTable
),
TheOrdinalPositionOfColumns AS
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
),
Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT Ndx, Id, col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY col DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM 
    MyTableWithRowId tbl
    UNPIVOT
    (
      col for Ndx in(col1, col2, col3)
    ) p
)
SELECT topoc.ORDINAL_POSITION AS ColumnOrdinalPosition
FROM Unpivoted
JOIN TheOrdinalPositionOfColumns topoc ON Unpivoted.Ndx = topoc.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE Rnk = 1;
```

[Updated Fiddle with Giorgi's Column naming](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b7bc/4)

Comment: This will not work if cols names are:  `SomeCol  OtherCol  WhatCol`.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b7bc/1

Comment: Your answer looks good. However I just need the index (1 instead of col1). Could you please modify your answer?

Comment: @YukiSakura I have - the second query will return the ordinal of the column. You'll need to guard against changes to the DDL when creating the table, and prevent DDL modifications to the column structure.

Comment: @StuartLC: I visited the SQL fiddle example. The result is 1, 3 while it should be 3, 1. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @YukiSakura you'll need something to order the table by, which we can pull through (you are currently getting the natural order of the table, which could be anything). Why not add an identity column to the table, which will replace the `newid()`

Comment: @StuartLC: mine already has identity column. I didn't post to keep example simple. Here is the real situation: I have a table with 7 columns including identity. I create a store procedure to add N more columns named "Extra1", "Extra2", ... "ExtraN" at runtime. Those N columns are updated with values. I want to find the maximum value of those N columns, then return the index 1-N. Do you know if we can get the number at the end of column name, "Extra1" -> 1, "Extra34" -> 34? I think you can improve your first answer.

Comment: @YukiSakura Just change `SELECT newId() AS Id` to 'SELECT MyIdentityColumn AS Id' and then add this right at the bottom `WHERE Rnk = 1 ORDER BY Id ASC;` to order by your original identity.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
select case 
           when col1 >= col2 and col1 >= col3 then 1
           when col2 >= col1 and col2 >= col3 then 2
           when col3 >= col1 and col3 >= col2 then 3
        end as ColIndex
from table
```

Comment: You dont need to have the third `when` instead write `else` :)

Comment: Yes but this way all answers will be the same :) Mine is different!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - then you should have used `IIF` :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
select 
case when col1 >= col2 and col1 >= col3 then 1
     when col2 >= col1 and col2 >= col3 then 2
  else 3 end as [index]
from myquestion_table
```

See a [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce911/2)

Comment: I think, with OP's latest comment `If they are equal, just ignore the later` you should change `>` to `>=` to pick first column.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, Thanks for pointing that; BTW when did OP commented ... didn't see that.

Comment: Yes I see that now; edited the question to include that point. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to include "undefined number of columns". Could you modify your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, without pivot.

-- You can add N number of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int primary key identity(1,1),[col1] int, [col2] int, [col3] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES
    (4, 6, 9),
    (7, 1, 5)
;
```

---

```
DECLARE @tempTable as table(name varchar(50),maxValue int)


DECLARE @maxColumn int
SELECT @maxColumn = max(ordinal_position)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'

DECLARE @maxRow int
SELECT @maxRow = Count(col1) FROM Table1


DECLARE @rowCounter int = 1
DECLARE @colCounter int = 1

DECLARE @columnName varchar(max)
DECLARE @colValue varchar(max)
DECLARE @q nvarchar(max)


DECLARE @maxValue int
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @FinalResult table (id int, columnName nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @rowId int

WHILE(@rowCounter <= @maxRow)
BEGIN
    WHILE (@colCounter <= @maxColumn)
    BEGIN

        SELECT @columnName = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1' and ordinal_position = @colCounter

        --select @columnName,@rowCounter,@colCounter

        SELECT @q = 'select @retvalOUT =' + @columnName + ' from Table1 where id = ' + cast(@rowCounter as NVARCHAR)

        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

        EXEC sp_executesql  @q,@ParmDefinition ,@retvalOUT = @maxValue OUT
        --select '@maxValue' + @maxValue

        INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@columnName,@maxValue)

        SET @colCounter = @colCounter + 1
    END



SELECT @rowId = maxValue FROM @tempTable WHERE name LIKE 'id' -- Primary key column

INSERT INTO @FinalResult(id,columnName)
SELECT TOP 1 @id,name FROM @tempTable WHERE name not like 'id' ORDER BY maxvalue DESC

DELETE FROM @tempTable

--select * from @FinalResult

SET @colCounter = 1
SET @rowCounter = @rowCounter + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @FinalResult
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another pivot solution, it is a bit shorter than the other pivot solution:

```
DECLARE @t table
(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
INSERT @t 
SELECT 4,8,9 union all SELECT 7,1,5 

;WITH addrownumber AS
(
  SELECT 
    rn = row_number() over (order by (select 1)),
    *
  FROM @t
)
, unpiv AS
(
  SELECT 
    rn, 
    value, 
    colname, 
    ordinalposition = row_number() over (partition by rn order by (select 1)),
    rn2 = row_number() over (partition by rn order by value DESC, rn)
  FROM addrownumber as p  
  UNPIVOT
  (value FOR colname IN           
  ([col1], [col2], [col3])) AS unpvt  
  -- since you need all columns to be mentioned in pivot, you can set up
  --  the ordinal order here, by putting in columns in the right order.
)
SELECT ordinalposition, value, colname
FROM unpiv
WHERE rn2 = 1
```

Result:

```
ordinalposition value   colname
3               9       col3
1               7       col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select case 
     when col1 >= col2 and col1 >= col3 then 1
     when col2 >= col1 and col2 >= col3 then 2
     else 3
     end as ind
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example, but it would be something like:

```
select case when col1 > col2 and col1 > col3 then col1
       when col2> col3 then col2
       else col3 end as greatestColumn
   from table
```